# How can I make inverse/forward PDF searching mark and navigate to the line of the code?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I use TeX Live 2011, WinEdt 6.0 and SumatraPDF, the inverse and forward PDF search can only mark and navigate to the paragraph, how to make them point to the line ?

Comment: Have you written the entire paragraph on a single line in your .tex file? You can see the line numbers by selecting View --> Line numbers.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. yes, I write the entire paragraph on a single line, it's word wrap. That's the reason. Thanks. So I should break the line by hand, then the inverse search can mark the line.

Comment: Yep, that's right. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a text file, lines are separated by a newline character, which you get by hitting enter. Even if a single line is broken by the editor (word wrap), as far as SyncTeX is concerned, it is still just a single line.

Take the following screenshot from WinEdt. You'll see that even though the first part is divided over several lines in the editor, everything is on line number four of the file.

[image]

The above predictably gives this output:

[image]

If I in Sumatra double click anywhere in the "All of this text is written on the same line"-part, WinEdt highlights line four:

[image]

If I double click "This is on a new line", I get

[image]

and double clicking the last sentence gives

[image]

Many prefer either creating a new line for every 65-80 characters, or having one sentence per line, which is beneficial both for synchronization and version control.